# Cannot send data from Linux VM to Windows Host

Tags: windows, networking, firewall, linux-networking, windows-firewall

I am trying to send data packets using SOME/IP Common API from my Linux VM. However, the data is not reaching to the Windows Host application. I have tried dumping the data packets using tcpdump, what I notice from the pcap log is, it says `42 9.070963    192.168.56.107  192.168.56.1    ICMP    142 Destination unreachable (Host administratively prohibited)`

[image]

Host IP: 192.168.56.1

VM IP: 192.168.56.107

I can ping on both sides without any issues. Previously, I followed one of the guide from [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/225155/virtualbox-how-to-set-up-networking-so-both-host-and-guest-can-access-internet). This helped me to ping from VM to my Host. But still the application side, its not able to get the data from the Linux VM. My current development PC is under the corporate network. Not sure that it could be one of the issue.

However the weird thing I notice is I was able to get the data if I run the same app from my Ubuntu VM. The current VM I am using is a Debian based VM.

Basically:
Ubuntu VM - works

Debian based VM - not working

Comment: Check your firewall.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have checked my firewall and theres where I added the inbound rules to allow the connection from the VM to my host. That only works for ping now. However, sending packets from the VM to my host is not working yet. One thing for sure is since this is a corporate device, I cant turn off the firewall too.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that you should check the firewall in the VM, not the host.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I am not really sure how to check the firewall in the VM. I tried searching for firewall, ufw, firewalld. Nothing pops up in the terminal. Do you know how to check that since this is a Debian based VM. Certain things are not similar with Ubuntu OS.

Comment: Hmm. If you didn't install a firewall, then there probably isn't one. But if you didn't install the OS in the VM yourself, then whoever created the VM may have installed something you are unaware of.

Comment: Oh gosh thats bad. I just directly run the .vdi image only. Not sure who created the image. Does VM iptables is useful for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue my clearing my iptables firewall rules. This is the command which helped me.

`sudo /usr/sbin/iptables -F`

This command will flush all the current rules. With the `sudo /usr/sbin/iptables -L -v` it shows all the current rules in the VM. From the view I could view that one of the rules is set to `REJECT`.