# Can ping from host to VM but can't ping from VM to host

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtual-machines, virtualbox

I have Ubuntu 22.04 Server VM on Windows 11 host with VirtualBox.

The Windows host IP is `192.168.14.11` and the VM IP is `192.168.14.22`.

When I ping from the Windows host to the VM I get a reply.
But when I ping from the Ubuntu VM to the Windows host (`192.168.14.11`) I get no response.

`ufw` is inactive

The connection is bridged

Comment: Could be windows firewall / defender?

Comment: Everything seem to be OK, can't find anything that blocks it on the Windows side

Comment: It might be helpful if you included the full configuration for each (netmask, routes) and the bit inbetween (virtualbox network) also to check if its only ICMP impacted or if it is all IP traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1114074/971292) to fix your issue. It was provided by [user658182](https://serverfault.com/users/132774/user658182)